# Unable to load multilevel JSON into data frame using R

Tags: r, json, dataframe, jsonlite, rjsonio

I am unable to load this nested JSON into a data frame.

```
require(RJSONIO)
sample_json2 <- '[{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50b59cd75bed76f46522c34e" },         "student_id" : 0, "class_id" : 2, "scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "score" : 57.92947112575566 }, { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 21.24542588206755 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 68.19567810587429 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 67.95019716560351 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 18.81037253352722 } ] }

,{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50b59cd75bed76f46522c34f" }, "student_id" : 0,      "class_id" : 28, "scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "score" : 39.17749400402234 }, { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 78.44172815491468 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 20.81782269075502 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 70.44520452408949 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 50.66616327819226 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 53.84983118363991 } ] }

,{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50b59cd75bed76f46522c350" }, "student_id" : 0,    "class_id" : 5, "scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "score" : 88.22950674232497 }, { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 79.28962650427184 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 18.66254946562674 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 40.28154176513361 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 1.23735944117882 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 88.96101200683958 } ] }

,{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50b59cd75bed76f46522c351" }, "student_id" : 0, "class_id" : 16, "scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "score" : 59.1805667559299 }, { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 47.58960202938239 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 6.48470951607214 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 68.33519637418685 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 78.53068038180965 } ] }

,{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50b59cd75bed76f46522c352" }, "student_id" : 0, "class_id" : 24, "scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "score" : 4.444435759027499 }, { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 28.63057857803885 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 86.79352850434199 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 83.9164548767836 } ] }

,{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50b59cd75bed76f46522c353" }, "student_id" : 0, "class_id" : 30, "scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "score" : 14.34345947841966 }, { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 47.65945482174327 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 83.42772189120254 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 49.86812935368258 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 39.85525554437086 } ] }

,{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50b59cd75bed76f46522c354" }, "student_id" : 0, "class_id" : 7, "scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "score" : 18.20492211025179 }, { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 60.4769945611789 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 75.62999921143397 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 72.41228797373115 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 74.06744381708968 } ] }]'
```

I tried using
`json_file2 <- fromJSON(sample_json2, flatten = TRUE)` for jsonlite package but it still has scores as a concatenated list.

I later tried lapply but the output in data frame is not in desired format. Its a list which will not make sense to any reader. Note that I am new to R so just following online blogs and trying to derive the output. Below is my code using lapply.

```
json_file2 <- fromJSON(sample_json2)
df <- lapply(json_file2, function(play){
    data.frame(matrix(unlist(play, recursive = TRUE), byrow = FALSE))
})
```

My desired output format would be to have 5 rows with each type of score in one row. I would also prefer if I can retain all column tags in the column names. Eg: _id.$oid, student_id, class_id, type, Scores.type, scores.score. But the format below will also work just fine.

```
$oid,                  student_id   class_id   type     score
50b59cd75bed76f46522c35    0            7      exam     75.62
50b59cd75bed76f46522c354   0            7      quiz     59.62
50b59cd75bed76f46522c354   0            7    homework   59.62
50b59cd75bed76f46522c354   0            7    Homework   59.62
```

Can someone please help me resolve this problem? Many thanks.

Comment: This looks like the result of a mongodb query, right? perhaps you could write your aggregation query to unwind the arrays and construct the result in the required format for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to SO!

I agree with @SymbolixAU that it's easier to format your mongo query, however, in case that isn't possible, I ended up making an attempt at it.

Please note that this code is just a very ugly and dirty solution, and I'm just learning a learner of R yet too, but it should just get you started. I used the `tidyverse` in here, as you did not specify if it had to use base R. Go [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/learn/) in case you're not familiar with it.

```
library(tidyverse)
json_file <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(sample_json2, flatten = TRUE, simplify = TRUE)

df <- json_file %>%
    unlist(recursive = F) %>%
    matrix(ncol = 4, byrow = T) %>% # Converts the data to a matrix
    as_data_frame %>% # Converts to tibble, for easier handling
    mutate(V4 = map(V4, ~ data.frame(
         matrix(unlist(.), ncol = 2, byrow = T), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    )) %>%
    unnest(V1, V2, V3) %>%
    unnest(V4) %>% # Can't do both on a single unnest
    mutate(X2 = as.numeric(X2), V2 = as.integer(V2), V3 = as.integer(V3)) %>%
    rename(oid = V1, student_id = V2, class_id = V3, type = X1, score = X2)
```

You'll end up with this:

```
> df
# A tibble: 36 x 5
   oid                      student_id class_id type     score
   <chr>                         <int>    <int> <chr>    <dbl>
 1 50b59cd75bed76f46522c34e          0        2 exam      57.9
 2 50b59cd75bed76f46522c34e          0        2 quiz      21.2
 3 50b59cd75bed76f46522c34e          0        2 homework  68.2
 4 50b59cd75bed76f46522c34e          0        2 homework  68.0
 5 50b59cd75bed76f46522c34e          0        2 homework  18.8
 6 50b59cd75bed76f46522c34f          0       28 exam      39.2
 7 50b59cd75bed76f46522c34f          0       28 quiz      78.4
 8 50b59cd75bed76f46522c34f          0       28 homework  20.8
 9 50b59cd75bed76f46522c34f          0       28 homework  70.4
10 50b59cd75bed76f46522c34f          0       28 homework  50.7
# ... with 26 more rows
```

Note: I had a very similar problem, that's why I'm sharing the code, but please note that this isn't encouraged by SO standards...

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. However, now I'm trying to get the output in tidydata format such that each variable has a column and there is one single row for one observation(the resultant row would be:oid, student_id,class_id,exam, quiz, homework, homework, homework). The scores will be provided in respective columns. I tried converting long dataset to wide using "spread(df, type, score)". But because of duplicate homeworks types, I'm not able to do that. Can you think of a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Also, what did you do there inside the mutate function, with map and unlist(.) Function? Can you please explain that so that I can logically reconstruct your solution on other use cases? Please forgive my lack of understanding since I'm new to R. Appreciate your help on this so far